# Can I use Live Mesh with my Live Groups account?

Tags: online-storage, office-365

I have a Windows Live account and use the Mesh drive to synchronize some various files and photos from work and home.

I recently setup a Live groups account, which includes 5GB of storage for the group.

Is there a way to configure Live Mesh to synchronize files in the groups skydrive account, so that I could have files in the group synchronized directly to my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Mesh and Live Groups are two separate products and you have two separate accounts. Currently there is no such Sync feature between the two. You would have to manually do whatever you wish to.